# JQuery $(x).find(y).each(function...) only returning single value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues with results from **JQuery** `$().find().each(function (i,e)...)`

In the `$(e).find('option:selected').each()` it is logging all of the entries into the console as intended, however, when adding to my created object `workstation.input {}`,  it is only adding the last value of the last option selected.

#### HTML (created by JS)

```
for (var i = 0; i < workstation.verifications.length; i++)
{ 
    var verfication = workstation.verifications[i];  

    //defining the input field based on object "type" (See object def): 
    if (verfication.type == 'text')
    {
        var $input = $('<input/>').attr('type', verfication.type).attr('verfication-name', verfication.name).addClass('col form-control'); 
    } 
    else if (verfication.type == 'choice')
    {
        var $input = $('<select/>').addClass('form-control')
                .append($('<option/>').text('Good').attr("value", "Good"))
                .append($('<option/>').text('N/A').attr("value", "N/A"))
                .append($('<option/>').text('Bad').attr("value", "Bad"))
    }

    if (verfication['title']) 
    { 
        $formTable.append(
            $('<div/>').text(verfication['title']).attr("id", 'workstationFormSectionHeader')
        ); 

    }
    
    else if(!verfication['title'])
    {
        $formTable.append(
            $('<div/>').addClass('row input-group').append($('<div/>').addClass('input-group-text col-sm-3').text(verfication.name))
                .append($('<div/>').append($input).addClass('col'))); 
    }
}
```

#### JQuery

```
 function get_form_data() { 
    var data = {workstation: []}; 

    $('.workstation-form').each(function (i,e) {
        var workstation = { 
            name: $(e).attr('workstation-name'), 
            input : {}, 
        }; 

        $(e).find('input').each(function(i,e2) { 
            
            //check for empty
            if ($(e2).val() == "") { 
                return; 
            }

            workstation.input[$(e2).attr('verfication-name')] = $(e2).val();

        }); 

        $(e).find('option:selected').each(function(i,e2){
            if ($(e2).val() == "") { 
                return; 
            }

            console.log($(e2)); 
            
            workstation.input[$(e2).attr('verfication-name')] = $(e2).val();
        })
            
        
        

        data.workstation.push(workstation); 
        //data.controllers.push(controller); 

    }); 

    return data; 
}
```

Here is a snap of the results in the broswer:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su9DG.jpg)

Comment: welcome! please provide an example html

Comment: When debugging, is $(e2).attr('verfication-name') the expected value?  I would also check $(e2).val() to see what that contains.  Can you give an example of what workstation.input[$(e2).attr('verfication-name')] = $(e2).val() should resolve to?

Comment: Yeah, so actually, I missed that too, but if i just added the verfication-name attribute to the HTML, an example would be  "example Verfication" : "Good" as in the value of the selected option.Right now it actually returns "undefined" : "Good". Good being the default :selected on my options.

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if you included an example of what `workstation` in your first code block contains, and/or a copy of the generated HTML instead of the script that generates it  (assuming that that first script is working as intended.)

Comment: That "Bad" value that you're showing is assigned to an unassigned property.  Maybe in each iteration it's not finding the property you want so the property is unassigned and that unassigned property gets overwritten each time so it only displays the last value.  You should try to get that fixed first.

Comment: Baboom! lol. Nailed it man! Added it, and I am now display all of the selected inputs. Thank you sir!